# Find overlapping Events in SQL and retaining the longer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I trying to filter my event table, to do some statistics, and the objective is to exclude events from one object that already has an Event active when that event occur.

For example:
ObjectId 4 triggered the Event 1, but during the execution of this event it also triggered the Event 2.
Since the Event 2 is inside the time frame of the execution of the Event 1 needs to be discarded.

```
DateIni             DateEnd               ObjectId  Description
2021-04-24 11:59:24 2021-04-24 12:00:24   4         Event 1
2021-04-24 11:59:25 2021-04-24 12:00:23   4         Event 2
2021-04-23 20:23:35 2021-04-23 20:24:35   11        Event 3
2021-04-23 20:23:37 2021-04-23 20:24:32   11        Event 4
2021-04-23 15:17:12 2021-04-23 15:18:12   2         Event 5
2021-04-23 15:17:14 2021-04-23 15:18:09   2         Event 6
```

I am doing this, but no success until now.

```
from Table A
INNER join Table B
    on (A.DateEnd < B.DateIni AND A.DateIni >= B.DateEnd)
    or (A.DateEnd >= B.DateIni AND A.DateIni <= B.DateEnd)
    or (A.DateEnd > B.DateIni AND A.DateIni < B.DateEnd)
    or (A.DateEnd <= B.DateIni AND A.DateIni > B.DateEnd)
    and B.ObjectId = A.ObjectId 
    and B.Description != A.Description
```

Any suggestion on how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible for an event to be included where the dates don't overlap?  If not - then it would be simpler to just use row_number() over the set and get the first event.

You can do something like this - there may be better options, but this should work:

```
 --==== Sample data
Declare @testData Table (DateIni datetime, DateEnd datetime, ObjectId int, Description varchar(30));
 Insert Into @testData (DateIni, DateEnd, ObjectId, [Description])
 Values ('2021-04-24 11:59:24', '2021-04-24 12:00:24',  4, 'Event 1')
      , ('2021-04-24 11:59:25', '2021-04-24 12:00:23',  4, 'Event 2')
      , ('2021-04-24 12:59:25', '2021-04-24 13:00:23',  4, 'Event 7')
      , ('2021-04-23 20:23:35', '2021-04-23 20:24:35', 11, 'Event 3')
      , ('2021-04-23 20:23:37', '2021-04-23 20:24:32', 11, 'Event 4')
      , ('2021-04-23 21:23:37', '2021-04-23 21:24:32', 11, 'Event 8')
      , ('2021-04-23 15:17:12', '2021-04-23 15:18:12',  2, 'Event 5')
      , ('2021-04-23 15:17:14', '2021-04-23 15:18:09',  2, 'Event 6')
      , ('2021-04-23 16:17:14', '2021-04-23 16:18:09',  2, 'Event 9');

 --==== Result using above sample data
   With previousDates
     As (
 Select *
      , PreviousEndDate = lag(td.DateEnd, 1) over(Partition By td.ObjectId Order By td.DateIni)
      , PreviousStartDate = lag(td.DateIni, 1) over(Partition By td.ObjectId Order By td.DateIni)
   From @testData               td
        )
 Select pd.DateIni
      , pd.DateEnd
      , pd.ObjectId
      , pd.Description
   From previousDates           pd     
  Where 1 = Case When pd.DateIni Between pd.PreviousStartDate And pd.PreviousEndDate Then 0
                 When pd.DateEnd Between pd.PreviousStartDate And pd.PreviousEndDate Then 0
                 Else 1
             End;
```

Now - if all we are concerned with is when the next event started - and if that next event started before the previous event completed:

```
 --==== Result using above sample data
   With previousDates
     As (
 Select *
      , PreviousEndDate = lag(td.DateEnd, 1) over(Partition By td.ObjectId Order By td.DateIni)
   From @testData               td
        )
 Select pd.DateIni
      , pd.DateEnd
      , pd.ObjectId
      , pd.Description
   From previousDates           pd     
  Where pd.PreviousEndDate Is Null
     Or pd.PreviousEndDate < pd.DateIni;
```

Or - we can determine if this event is the first event and filter that way:

```
 --==== Result using above sample data
   With firstEvents
     As (
 Select *
      , isFirstEvent = iif(lag(td.DateEnd, 1, td.DateEnd) over(Partition By td.ObjectId Order By td.DateIni) <= td.DateEnd, 1, 0)
   From @testData               td
        )
 Select fe.DateIni
      , fe.DateEnd
      , fe.ObjectId
      , fe.Description
   From firstEvents             fe
  Where fe.isFirstEvent = 1;
```

Comment: Yes, its possible to exist an event that doesn't have any overlap.
The first option works great because in the majority of the cases both events finish around the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You would simply use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.objectid = t.objectid and
                        t2.dateini < t.dateini and
                        t2.dateend > t.dateend
                 );
```

For performance, you want an index on `(objectid, dateini, dateend)`.

Comment: I tried that to but since that are events that have the same DateIni and DateEnd, this solution can discard Events that are not supposed to be discarded.

Comment: @DiogoMartins . . . I don't understand.  This won't discard events that have the same ini end end dates.

Comment: I am sorry, I made a mistake when a copied the function. It works, but compared to the other answer its slower.

Comment: @DiogoMartins . . . This doesn't make the same assumptions about the data, so it is actually a better fit for the question you actually asked.